# Parse Issue - Expected unqualified-id - #include <array> Compile Error

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I'm currently building this ios card game app using objective-c++. Out of what seems to be nowhere, I started experiencing a Parse Issue - Expected unqualified-id when trying to use `#include <array>`. I've never had this problem before today. Any clarity or direction would be greatly appreciated! I have already double-checked my compiler settings to ensure it knows I'm using c++.

[Shows where the error is flagged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K73vt.png)

[Compiler Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzYXV.png)

[Compiler Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SGUJ.png)

[Shows Build time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d13U.png)

```
#ifndef Pack_hpp
#define Pack_hpp

#include "Card.hpp"
#include <array>
#include <string>
class Pack {
public:
  Pack();

private:
    //1 deck == 52 cards
    //3 decks == 156
    //6 decks == 312
  static const int PACK_SIZE = 312;
  std::array<Card, PACK_SIZE> cards;
  int next; //index of next card to be dealt
};
```

Error Log

```
In file included from /Users/MM/Documents/C++PROJECTS/C++CoreGame/Pack.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/MM/Documents/C++PROJECTS/C++CoreGame/Pack.hpp:18:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/array:123:1: error: expected unqualified-id
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
^
In file included from /Users/MM/Documents/C++PROJECTS/C++CoreGame/Pack.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/MM/Documents/C++PROJECTS/C++CoreGame/Pack.hpp:17:
In file included from /Users/MM/Documents/C++PROJECTS/C++CoreGame/Card.hpp:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:503:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:866:37: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD'
#define _LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD namespace std { inline namespace _LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE {
                                    ^
1 error generated.
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

Card::Card()
    : rank(), suit() {}

//REQUIRES rank is one of "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
//  "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
//  suit is one of "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"
//EFFECTS Initializes Card to specified rank and suit
Card::Card(const std::string &rank_in, const std::string &suit_in)
: rank(rank_in), suit(suit_in) {}

//EFFECTS Returns the rank
std::string Card::get_rank() const
{
    return rank;
}

//EFFECTS Returns the suit.  Does not consider trump.
std::string Card::get_suit() const
{
    return suit;
}

//EFFECTS Returns true if card is a face card (Jack, Queen, King or Ace)
bool Card::is_face() const
{
    if((get_rank() == Card::RANK_JACK) || (get_rank() == Card::RANK_QUEEN) || (get_rank() == Card::RANK_KING)|| (get_rank() == Card::RANK_ACE))
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is lower value than rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator<(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs)
{
    int lhs_RankWeight = 0;

    int rhs_RankWeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RANKS; i++)
    {
        if (lhs.get_rank() == RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[i])
        {
            lhs_RankWeight = i;
        }
        if (rhs.get_rank() == RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[i])
        {
            rhs_RankWeight = i;
        }
    }

        //compare left hand and right hand weights
        if (lhs_RankWeight < rhs_RankWeight)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is higher value than rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator>(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs)
{
    int lhs_RankWeight = 0;

    int rhs_RankWeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RANKS; i++)
    {
        if (lhs.get_rank() == RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[i])
        {
            lhs_RankWeight = i;
        }
        if (rhs.get_rank() == RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[i])
        {
            rhs_RankWeight = i;
        }
    }


    //compare left hand and right hand weights
    if (lhs_RankWeight > rhs_RankWeight)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is same card as rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator==(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs)
{
    if (((lhs.get_suit() == rhs.get_suit()) && (lhs.get_rank() == rhs.get_rank())))
    {
        return true;
    }
   else
   {
       return false;
    }
}

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is not the same card as rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator!=(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs)
{
    if (((lhs.get_suit() != rhs.get_suit()) || (lhs.get_rank() != rhs.get_rank())))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//REQUIRES suit is a valid suit
//EFFECTS returns the next suit, which is the suit of the same color
std::string Suit_next(const std::string &suit)
{
    if(suit == Card::SUIT_SPADES)
    {
        return Card::SUIT_CLUBS;
    }
     if(suit == Card::SUIT_CLUBS)
     {
        return Card::SUIT_HEARTS;
     }
    if(suit == Card::SUIT_HEARTS)
    {
        return Card::SUIT_DIAMONDS;
    }
    if(suit == Card::SUIT_DIAMONDS)
    {
        return Card::SUIT_SPADES;
    }
    return 0;
}

//EFFECTS Prints Card to stream, for example "Two of Spades"
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Card &card)
{
   return os << card.get_rank() << " of " << card.get_suit();
}
```

Card.hpp

```
#ifndef Card_hpp
#define Card_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


class Card
{
public:
int value;
  // rank and suit names
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_TWO = "Two";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_THREE = "Three";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_FOUR = "Four";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_FIVE = "Five";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_SIX = "Six";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_SEVEN = "Seven";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_EIGHT = "Eight";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_NINE = "Nine";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_TEN = "Ten";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_JACK = "Jack";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_QUEEN = "Queen";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_KING = "King";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_ACE = "Ace";

  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_SPADES = "Spades";
  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_HEARTS = "Hearts";
  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_CLUBS = "Clubs";
  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_DIAMONDS = "Diamonds";

  //EFFECTS Initializes Card to empty hand
  Card();

  //REQUIRES rank is one of "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
  //  "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
  //  suit is one of "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"
  //EFFECTS Initializes Card to specified rank and suit
  Card(const std::string &rank_in, const std::string &suit_in);

  //EFFECTS Returns the rank
  std::string get_rank() const;

  //EFFECTS Returns the suit.
  std::string get_suit() const;

  //EFFECTS Returns true if card is a face card (Jack, Queen, King or Ace)
  bool is_face() const;

private:
    std::string rank;
    std::string suit;
};

// Suits in order from lowest suit to highest suit.
constexpr const char* const SUIT_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[] = {
  Card::SUIT_SPADES,
  Card::SUIT_HEARTS,
  Card::SUIT_CLUBS,
  Card::SUIT_DIAMONDS
};
const int NUM_SUITS = 4;

// Ranks in order from lowest rank to highest rank.
constexpr const char* const RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[] = {
  Card::RANK_TWO,
  Card::RANK_THREE,
  Card::RANK_FOUR,
  Card::RANK_FIVE,
  Card::RANK_SIX,
  Card::RANK_SEVEN,
  Card::RANK_EIGHT,
  Card::RANK_NINE,
  Card::RANK_TEN,
  Card::RANK_JACK,
  Card::RANK_QUEEN,
  Card::RANK_KING,
  Card::RANK_ACE
};
const int NUM_RANKS = 13;

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is lower value than rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator<(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs);

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is higher value than rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator>(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs);

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is same card as rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator==(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs);

//EFFECTS Returns true if lhs is not the same card as rhs.
//  Does not consider trump.
bool operator!=(const Card &lhs, const Card &rhs);

//REQUIRES suit is a valid suit
//EFFECTS returns the next suit, which is the suit of the same color
std::string Suit_next(const std::string &suit);

//EFFECTS Prints Card to stream, for example "Two of Spades"
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Card &card);

#endif
*
```

Comment: in c++ you write `#include<array>`, not `#import`. If you mix objective-c and c++, make sure the file has extension `.mm`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I am in fact using #include<array>. The file in question is a straight c++ file the extension I'm using is .hpp for header and .cpp for the main file.

Comment: [Edit] your question to Include all of your code in the question _as text_, not images. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** the question has changed quite a lot since it was originally posted. Here is the eventual answer but I'll keep what I wrote before below.

The problem is the lone asterisk (`*`) which seems to have snuck in at the end of your `Card.hpp` file.

The reason the error is showing up in `<array>` is because `#include` just performs text substitution, and because `<array>` is included immediately after `Card.hpp` inside `Pack.hpp`:

```
#include "Card.hpp"
#include <array>
```

The asterisk *might* not be a problem depending on what follows it, but the code inside `<array>` of course does not expect to follow a rogue `*`, hence the compile error.

---

**Previous answer** - Kept for posterity - this was posted in response to the question just containing `Pack.hpp`. Follow the comments below to find out how we got to the answer in the end.

The include guard

```
#ifndef Pack_hpp
#define Pack_hpp
```

suggests this code is from inside a file named `Pack.hpp`, that is, a header file.

I suspect it is being included from a `.m` (pure Objective-C) file, either directly or transitively, and an Objective-C compiler cannot make sense of this C++ code. ([Transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) in this case means it's included by another header file which is included by a `.m` file, or it is included by a header file which is included by another header file, etc. forming a chain ultimately leading to a header file which is included directly by the `.m` file.)

Make sure you only `#include` this file from `.cpp` or `.mm` files.

Note that `clang` will actually tell you the `#include` chain when it prints the error, you just need to follow it back to the file for the compilation unit to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve the issue yet. ```#include <array>```  is used inside ```Pack.hpp``` and this header file is only included in ```.cpp```,```.hpp```, and ```.mm``` files.                I attempted to follow what i believe is the ```clang``` #include chain you were referring to, shown in the "Shows Build time error" above. This chain of includes start with the ```.cpp```and ```.hpp``` files and end with ```3. Expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD'```

Comment: That screenshot didn't show any filenames though, so there was no way for me to tell. Another reason why copy-pasting the error as text is much better. Can you please update your question with the full error description and trace please? In Xcode, you can get to it via the report navigator (⌘9). Select the most recent build on the left, find the compilation unit where the error occurs in the list on the right, then click the log icon (4-5 horizontal lines) at the far right of that row. Copy that log output into your question and we'll stand a chance of seeing what's going on.

Comment: Actually, I'm wondering if the problem is actually in `Card.hpp`. If you swap the two includes for `<array>` and `"Card.hpp"`, does an error suddenly show up somewhere else entirely, or change in some other substantial way? If so, please post the contents of `Card.hpp` (especially towards the end of that file)

Comment: Incidentally, this sort of thing is why there's a policy on this site recommending you include a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question: trying to create that sample would likely quickly lead you towards where the error actually originates - and that's almost certainly code or configuration you haven't shared with us yet.

Comment: I apologize, I have added ```Pack.hpp```, ```Card.hpp```, ```Card.cpp``` and the error log. Also ```<array>``` is not mentioned in ```Card.hpp```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Is that asterisk (`*`) at the end of Card.hpp a copy-paste error or is it actually there? If it's actually there, that's your problem.

Comment: WOW ...That was, in fact, the problem. THANK YOU pmdj!

Comment: Cool, nothing to do with Objective-C++ then. :-) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off @pmdj's answer, I was coming against this same issue – the build error was popping up in AVAnimation this time (I was importing AVFoundation).

The answer for me was that I had *forgot* to add a character – the `;` following the closing `}` of a C++ class in a different file completely:

```
class SubclassSomething : public Something {

};   // <-----
```

It wasn't until I commented out the AVFoundation import line causing the build error that Xcode actually told me what was causing it.

Comment: Or if you were writing a obj-c++ object layer that is wrapping around a C++ library like me... forgetting your `@end` in your header will also trigger this same issue. That's effectively like forgetting your `;`

That only became evident once I commented out my entire implementation file.